# Prove that for any continuous on $[0,1]$ function: $\int_0^{\pi\over2}f(\sin x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi\over2}f(\cos x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals, solution-verification

> Prove that for any continuous on $[0,1]$ the following equality holds:
>   $$
> \int_0^{\pi\over2}f(\sin x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi\over2}f(\cos x)\,dx
> $$

I've basically used the King's rule, namely:
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx= \int_a^bf(a+b - x)\,dx
$$
So:
$$
\int_0^{\pi\over2}f(\sin x)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi\over2}f\left(\sin \left({\pi\over 2} - x\right)\right)\,dx
$$
But:
$$
\sin \left({\pi\over 2} - x\right) = \cos(x)
$$
Thus:
$$
\int_0^{\pi\over2}f\left(\sin \left({\pi\over 2} - x\right)\right)\,dx = \int_0^{\pi\over2}f(\cos x)\,dx
$$

I get why we need $f(x)$ to be continuous, however, I don't really understand why we require $f(x)$ to be continuous specifically on the range $[0, 1]$. Could you please explain that?

Comment: what is $c$? ${}{}$

Comment: @mathworker21 disregard $c$, I've misformulated the problem statement.

Comment: why do you need $f$ to be continuous? you said you get why. i don't get why

Comment: @mathworker21 this is the condition for Riemann's integrability. Yet a function might have a finite number of discontinuities and still be Riemann's integrable

Comment: It's not actually necessary that $f$ be continuous, but it's sufficient.

Comment: Often the assumption of continuity in integration problems at this level are just saying "don't worry too much about delicacies of integral convergence, change of variables etc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0\le x\le \frac \pi 2$ then $0\le\cos x\le 1$ and $0\le \sin x \le 1.$

Comment: ouch, feeling dumb now. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

We know that continuous functions are integrable. We can formulate a weaker version, assuming that the integrals exist, but with continuity we have this guaranteed. And arguments of $f$ are values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ in $[0,\pi/2]$ and this in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: indeed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both integrals are equal to $\int_0^1 \frac{f(u)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} du$.

In the first integral, use the substitution $u=\sin x$, and in the second $u=\cos x$.